# Product of Two systems with the same asymptotically stable fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I am trying to figure out the nature of a new dynamical system that is equal to the product of two dynamical systems with the same asymptotically stable fixed point.  For instance, if i have $x' = f(x)$ and $x' = g(x)$ and both have the same fixed point, what could be said about the nature of the fixed point for  system $x' = g(x)f(x)$?

Comment: I guess the dimension of $x$ is one or are you referring to more general dynamical systems?

Comment: Yes, this deals with one dimensional motion

Answer (score 1):

The equilibrium of the resulting system is unstable. Let $x^*$ an equilibrium of the two systems. Then, due to the asymptotic stability assumption of $x^*$ there is some $\epsilon>0$  such that

i) $f(x)<0$ and $g(x)<0$ for all $x\in (x^*,x^*+\epsilon)$

ii) $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in (x^*-\epsilon,x^*)$

This means that  $f(x)g(x)>0$ for all $x\in (x^*-\epsilon,x^*+\epsilon)$ except $x^*$ and thus all trajectories starting from $x^*+\epsilon_0$ with $\epsilon_0>0$ will grow away from $x^*$.

Comment: Could you have a case where it would be half stable?  For instance, if you consider the phase plots for the function f(x) = x*(3-x)*(4-x) and g(x) = x*(3-x) *(5-x), you will see an asymptotically stable fixed point at x = 3.  However, the phase plot for the product of the two (i.e. x^2 * (3-x)^2 * (5-x) *(4-x)) will show a half stable fixed point at x = 3

Comment: @Jamal Yes the fixed point is attracting from the left and repelling from the right. Thus trajectories starting within $(x^*-\epsilon,x^*)$ will converge asymptotically to $x^*$.